# Request array data with Ajax [Prestashop 1.7]

Tags: ajax, templates, module, request, prestashop

I need help with the use of ajax in my case. I override the ProductController class in a module that I customized and added a array that included the carriers of the product.

I direct this data in the template product.tpl and I use Bootstrap to display a link that opens a modal where the data is displayed.
[link Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLge4.png)

And I would like to have help using ajax so that the content of the modal updates without updating the page please.

Comment: I think the best way is to use a product tab hook in your module (e.g. hookdisplayproductadditionalinfo) to be able to add the information you need. Hook is being called in AJAX after product page is updated (ie variation change)

Comment: OK, but do you have any examples, I’m a beginner and I’d like to have at least one procedure to follow please